# Combine multiple text files into only one text file

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy, file

I would like to combine multiple text files into only one text file, and read all the contents in it. However, the codes read only one text file and save data taken from only one text file. The codes;

```
path = "/home/Documents/Python/"
     
read_files = glob.glob(path+"*.txt")

with open("contents.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I also tried nearly same another code. However, it couldn't convert string to float because the first rows in the text files contain # character.

```
x = np.array([float(raw) for raw in f.readlines()])
```

I am aware that there are also some other questions in stackoverflow, highlighting how to do it. Even though I tried them as well, I couldn't achieve it properly.

I will appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Since your question is also tagged with numpy, you can use numpy's loadtxt which will read in the data as a Numpy array. The `loadtxt` function supports reading / skipping columns of different types as well as headers. Then, you can concatenate all your arrays, and save it with `numpy.savetxt`. Alternatively, you can use the Pandas library which has a nicer interface to some of Numpy's data functions and representations.

Answer (score 2):

in case someone wants to use another method, these codes have worked for me. i have followed another path to find out a solution for my own question.

```
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
all = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    all.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(all, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:\\")


extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "C:\\combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```